# google-cloud-storage get blob key from blob in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get the blob key from a Blob after uploading to google cloud storage.

I'm using this api https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java
at the lastest verison.

There does not seem to be an api for this.

Is there any way to get the blob key for a blob?

Please note that my app does NOT run on GAE, it runs on jetty.

So is there a way to get the blob key for a storage blob from outside of GAE?

Comment: Could you clarify *exactly* what you mean by "blob key"? My understanding is that "blob key" is more associated with BlobStore than GCS. Could you give more context about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello Jon. the blob key is generally used to identify an object in the blobstore (see this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobKey) Only problem is that the api i'm linking to only works on GAE.

As far as i can tell you can generate a blob key (in GAE) by calling BlobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("/gs/" + bucket + "/" + blobname);

I need it only to integrate with an existing api we have that needs blob keys for access files.

Comment: So yes, that's to do with Blobstore. I know GCS and Blobstore are related, but Blobstore is GAE-specific as I understand it. If you're using an API which requires you to do something GAE-specific, then I suspect you will need to run at least some code in GAE. The API is effectively tying you to GAE. Now with "just plain GCS" you can definitely create public https links to blobs - would that be good enough instead? Are you able to modify the API you're talking to?

Comment: That should be good enough. and yes i can modify the api. (i was hoping to not have to :P but oh well). Can you point me in the right direction for the "public https links to blobs" you mention?

Comment: In https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource, it's `mediaLink`. Or you can just use `https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket}/{name}`